# MalformedByteSequenceException when parsing XML from URL in Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse a XML with the following code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new URL("http://www.cinemark.com.br/mobile/xml/films/").openStream());
```

But get the following error:

```
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(UTF8Reader.java:687)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:557)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1753)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.arrangeCapacity(XMLEntityScanner.java:1629)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipString(XMLEntityScanner.java:1667)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:196)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:812)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:347)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)
    at Programacao.main(Programacao.java:53)
```

Accessing [the url](http://www.cinemark.com.br/mobile/xml/films/), you can see there are some portuguese characters, and seeing the response, I could see the first line of the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
```

So I tried doing this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.cinemark.com.br/mobile/xml/films/");

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

InputStream ism = url.openStream();
InputSource is = new InputSource(ism);
is.setEncoding("iso-8859-1");

Document doc = db.parse(is.getByteStream());
```

But I still got the EXACT same error.
How can I parse the xml using a different encondig?

Also, how can I know if the xml is really in the encoding described in the file?

I'm using JDK 1.7.0_51 on Fedora Linux 20

Thanks

**SOLUTION**

What I did to solve the problem, based on Seelenvirtuose answer:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.cinemark.com.br/mobile/xml/films/");

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

InputStream ism = url.openStream();
GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(ism);
Reader decoder = new InputStreamReader(gis);
InputSource is = new InputSource(decoder);

Document doc = db.parse(is);
```

Comment: I suppose, setting encoding has nothing to do with getByteStream. The last one returns just bytes. Encoding is a meta-information about how to interpret these bytes, but with getBytes there's no such interpretation at all.

Comment: Parse the input source directly and not getting the byte stream as @kirilloid mentioned.

Comment: may b encoding format is wrong...first check the format

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but if I just passed the Input Source directly, I would get:
    org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Content is not allowed in prolog.
I also had to do what @Seelenvirtuose said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in behavior is as following:

When accessing the URL in a browser, after some time it displays:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<cinemark>
  <films>
    <film ...>...</film>
    ...
  </films>
</cinemark>
```

However, when simply running [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) (for example), then you get an output similar to:

```
‹      ¬YMsÛ6½ûW`xôT¨Oªc) [...]
```

So, what actually is happening? Easy: This is called [HTTP compresson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression). So when running the following command

> curl -o films.zip http://www.cinemark.com.br/mobile/xml/films/

you will get a file called `films.zip` that contains a single file called `films`, which in turn contains the expected XML document.

So, what you should do is: Take the output stream as a compressed stream, extract the content, and parse that.

Comment: You are right, it was compressed in gunzip format.
Thank you very much.